# I want to add some style by myself, but the page seems does not recognize

Tags: html, angularjs

In my code I want to add the color for the $scope.originalGurus[i]['symbols_type'][j], the color is depends on the content of  $scope.originalGurus[i]['symbols_type'][j].

in my code, if that is "New" or "Add" it must be green. But for else, it must be red.
And I only want to add color for the $scope.originalGurus[i]['symbols_type'][j], not includes $scope.originalGurus[i]['symbols'][j]

the result I want is like : ISNPY:(color is black) New(color is green)
in my code "ISNPY" is store in the $scope.originalGurus[i]['symbols'][j],but the "New" is store in the $scope.originalGurus[i]['symbols_type'][j]

I use angularJs.

My code as follows:

```
 for(var j = 0; j < $scope.originalGurus[i]['symbols'].length; j++){
            if($scope.originalGurus[i]['symbols_type'][j] == "New" || $scope.originalGurus[i]['symbols_type'][j] == "Add"){
                $scope.originalGurus[i]['symbols_show'][j] = $scope.originalGurus[i]['symbols'][j] + ": <p style=\"color:green;\">" + $scope.originalGurus[i]['symbols_type'][j] + "</p>";
            }else {
                $scope.originalGurus[i]['symbols_show'][j] = $scope.originalGurus[i]['symbols'][j] + ": <p style=\"color:red;\">" + $scope.originalGurus[i]['symbols_type'][j] + "</p>";
            }
        }
```

And the html is very simple:

```
<div ng-repeat="symbol in gurus.symbols_show">
    {{symbol}}
</div>
```

As the result, the page will display like:

```
ABC: <p style="color:green;">ABC</p>
```

My data like this:

```
[
{
    "symbols": [
      "ISNPY",
      "COWN",
      "OSUR"
    ],
    "symbols_type": [
      "New",
      "New",
      "New"
    ]
  },
{...},{...}.{...}...]
```

It not meet my requirements, Any body knows the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create symbols_show at all.

Assuming your symbol_type and symbol are natural arrays:

```
<div ng-repeat="symbol_type in gurus.symbols_type track by $index">
    {{gurus.symbols[$index]}}: <p ng-style="{color: (symbol_type == 'New' || symbol_type == 'Add') ? 'green' : 'red'}">{{symbol_type}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the $index?I use it, if only one record in my symbols and symbols_type, the display is correct, but if there are many, it shows nothing

Comment: $index is ng-repeat internal counter, it would be 0 for the first record, 1 for the second record and so on. I'm not sure why it won't work for multiple records, is there any error in console? Can you give some example for your data structure?

Comment: yes,there is an error:Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: symbol_type in gurus.symbols_type, Duplicate key: string:New, Duplicate value: New.
i add my code format in my question..

Comment: oh, then use `ng-repeat="symbol_type in gurus.symbols_type track by $index"` should do.

Comment: just add `track by $index` in ng-repeat

Comment: It works well now.Thanks for your help.Can you tell how to learn angularjs?

Comment: For me it's by experience. Will learn more when you use more and stumble across different questions. Good luck =)